# How to scale the viewport and the actual size in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SingleChildScrollView` and widgets in this `ScrollView` that I want to scale.

But when I scale the items, the `ScrollView` only accepts the original size and not the current size that was scaled. So I can't scroll to the bottom of the last widget.

Here is my code:

```js
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.5,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: InteractiveViewer(
         panEnabled: false,
         minScale: 0.1,
         maxScale: 10,
         scaleEnabled: false,
         child: Column(
            children: children,//Some more uninteresting widgets like containers and texts
         ),
      )
   ),
),
```

This is how it looks (here you can see the scaled text, which I can't scroll down)
(if the text would not be scaled by `Transform.scale`, then it would fit perfectly and I could scroll down the text to the bottom)
Screenshot of Output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Tfm.png)

How can I do, that the current size is accepted by the `ScrollView` with the scaling and I`m able to scroll to the bottom?